# Missing hardware after reinstall

Tags: windows-xp, serial-port

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T61 laptop.  I downloaded a security suite from my bank that caused conflicts with my previous installation of Windows XP.  So, I wiped out my hard drive and re-loaded window xp.

Now, unfortunately, I am missing the Ports (COM & LPT) entry in Device Manager.  I believe I have installed everything I was supposed to, but then again, I am a beginner at this and I am not sure.

Can anyone please let me know how to get this back?

Comment: ... and the details of your computer?  Is it a laptop that doesn't have serial or parallel ports?  Make and model of the machine?  Did you download and install *all* the hardware drivers for your machine?

Comment: Ooops sorry, I am a beginner. It is a laptop, ThinkPad Lenovo T61. It was loaded perfectly well untill I downloaded a security software from my bank web site, which for some reason conflicted with what I already had on my laptop. Hence I wiped clean everything and re-installed window xp.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Your question was closed because it's not clear what you're actually asking. Is there something that used to be there and now isn't? What are you trying to do with "Ports/LPT"? If you [edit] your question to include a bit more info we can go ahead and reopen it for you, but right now it's not answerable.

Comment: Listed under my device manager, I should have Ports (COM & LPT), but unfortunately that is no longer there. So I am asking how do I get it back? It might well be that I have not installed all the device drivers for my hardware. If so can you please point me out in the direction of the drivers for my laptop.

Comment: funny... I knew what you wanted.  I just needed more details about the hardware.  I didn't think the question was ambiguous, vague, overly broad, or rhetorical, and as far as incomplete, there are plenty of other questions left open that needed more details. At any rate, here is the Lenovo page for your drivers.  http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-67853 just select Windows XP from the Operating System pulldown, and download everything except the BIOS section, and the drivers that don't pertain to Windows XP

Comment: Question was closed due to leaving out details of your setup and what you needed for the end result and what brought you here. That someone did edit in another 80% from clarification comments is the reason it was closed as incomplete and ambiguous. Needing more details to answer is the definition of NARQ @bon

Comment: Bon Gart, thank you for the link. There are loads of drivers on that page. As the laptop is not functioning, I cannot go on the internet, so at this stage I would need to download the relevant drivers only using a separate PC. Once I get the laptop functioning I will connect to the net and download all the other drivers directly to the laptop. In view of this, can you  or anyone else please let me know which "category" from the pull down menu I should select containing the relevant drivers to re-instate Ports (COM & LPT) only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Just installed Windows 7, some things not working out-of-the-box](http://superuser.com/questions/418954/just-installed-windows-7-some-things-not-working-out-of-the-box)

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the the Lenovo ThinkVantage Tools from the Lenovo driver page.

Also look for the Intel chipset driver install if you cannot find the ThinkVantage tools